# Connect ADO.NET Entity Data Model to Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-6, ado.net-entity-data-model, npgsql

I'm creating an **ASP MVC 3** website. I have a **Postgresql** database - I'm using **Entity Framework 6** - I have referenced **Npgsql** and **Npgsql.EntityFramework** and installed **dotConnect for PostgreSQL**. The connection with the **Postgresql** database works fine - when I want to add a database connection I have **PostgreSQL server** in the data source list:

[image]

But when I want to add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model to the project there isn't **PostgreSQL server** in the data source list :

[image]

Comment: Can you help me please? I'm stuck, I don't know what to do...

Comment: *I have referenced Npgsql and Npgsql.EntityFramework and installed dotConnect for PostgreSQL*. Assuming you meant "removed" instead of "referenced"? If so: why? What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? My first guess here is that you installed only the 64-bit dotconnect driver, and your IDE is 32-bit, but that's just a guess, and one I'm not even sure makes sense in .NET. It's a common issue with ODBC.

Comment: Do you want to use Npgsql or dotConnect? Those two are different implementations of a PostgreSQL driver for .NET. Have you read the documentation at http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html?